electron-store returns "Property 'set' / 'get' does not exist on type"
I'm using electron-store for a demo electron project. In my main.ts process, I'm attempting to initialize the store and retrieve a simple settings object. It looks like this:
// main.ts
import Store, { Schema } from 'electron-store';

type settingsType = {
  settings: {
    environment: 'development' | 'test' | 'prod',
    refreshInterval: number,
  }
}

const schema: Schema<settingsType> = {
  settings: {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      environment: {
        type: 'string',
        enum: ['development', 'test', 'prod'],
        default: 'development',
      },
      refreshInterval: {
        type: 'number',
        minimum: 10000, // ten seconds
        maximum: 600000, // ten min
        default: 60000, // one min
      }
    },
    default: {},
    required: ['environment', 'refreshInterval'],
  }
}

const store = new Store<settingsType>({schema});

// ERROR: TS2339: Property 'get' does not exist on type 'ElectronStore<settingsType>'.
let settingsStore: settingsType = store.get('settings');

I think I'm defining everything as expected, but I'm still getting a TS error from the store.get call. What am I missing?

Try to downgrade electron-store version to 8.2.0
npm i electron-store@8.2.0. It helped in my case.

Hi @kiwibird77, welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like there's an issue for this open on the electron-store repository.

I got it to work with the example tsconfig mentioned in that issue, but VScode still complains about the property not existing. Any workarounds for this?

Aside from downgrading, adding "moduleResolution": "node16" to your tsconfig should also fix this issue. Also you will need to add a corresponding compilerOption.module to your tsconfig, just for good measures.
But then you will need to make sure you have "type": "module" in you package.json. Which may break, or fix, other package imports in your project. Plus you will probably need to modify your preload path when calling new BrowserWindow() to import an mjs file instead of a js one for your preload script like so: preload: join(__dirname, '../preload/index.mjs').
And if you make these changes, import paths will now need explicit file extensions so /code.js instead of /code. Plus keep in mind that global variables will now be shared so you may run into issues redeclaring vars. And in general your code will be compiled drastically different than it was before... so keep that in mind.
Or just downgrade if that works for you.
